# How can I form a parent child relation with these numbers?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, collections

I am trying to display data in parent-child form. The input data is :-

1

1.1

1.2

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.2.1

2.0

How can we display this data in hierarchy ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried anything though?

Comment: Yes I did. I have updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as how you haven't posted any code, I'm not going to either. I will offer you some direction though:

One way you can approach this is to read in the number and use the `.split()` method on the data. From there you can compare the two halves to the data you have, and assign relationships as you see fit.

For instance, you read in `1.0`, split, If the second half has a `0`, set it as root, and assign the parent node a value of `1`, then check the rest of the numbers. If the first half equals 1, then you assign it as a child of 1, if it's 2, assign to 2, ans so on...

Hope this helps and makes sense. Good luck.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Please suggest a solution for tree /hierarchy.